# Multiple scroll events jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a landing page and some section elements have to show when they top reach the 50% of the window. My problem is that when the first section reaches the point it animates but even the other sections got animated. I want to animate the first section and only when the other sections.
Here is my code:

```
/* Elements animation */
var wheight = $(window).height() / 2;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    inlineElements();
    $(window).off("scroll", inlineElements);
    accentElements();
    $(window).off("scroll", accentElements);
    lastElements();
    $(window).off("scroll", lastElements);
});
function inlineElements(e) {
    if ($(".inline-elem").offset().top >= wheight) {
        $(".inline-elem").each(function(i) {
            var el = $(this);
            var text = $(".fade-up-text");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.fadeIn(500).removeClass("hidden");
                text.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
            }, i * 500);
        });
    }
}
function accentElements(e) {
    if ($(".accent-elem").offset().top >= wheight) {
        $(".accent-elem").each(function(i) {
            var el = $(this);
            var trucker = $("#trucker");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.addClass("slideLeft").removeClass("hidden");
                trucker.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
            }, i * 500);
        });
    }
}
function lastElements(e) {
    if ($(".last-elem").offset().top >= wheight) {
        $(".last-elem").each(function(i) {
            var el = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
            }, i * 500);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I made a mistake to calculate the point to run the events elements. Below the working code with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the right code with the changes.

```
var halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  inlineElements();
  accentElements();
  lastElements();
});

function inlineElements() {
  var item = $(".inline-elem").offset().top;
  var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (item < (topWindow + halfHeight)) { // CHANGES HERE
  $(".inline-elem").each(function(i) {
      var img = $(this);
      var text = $(".fade-up-text");
      setTimeout(function() {
          img.fadeIn(2000).removeClass("hidden");
          text.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
      }, i * 500);
  });
 }
}

function accentElements() {
  var item = $(".accent-elem").offset().top;
  var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (item < (topWindow + halfHeight)) { // CHANGES HERE
   $(".accent-elem").each(function(i) {
      var el = $(this);
      var trucker = $("#trucker");
      setTimeout(function() {
          el.addClass("slideLeft").removeClass("hidden");
          trucker.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
      }, i * 500);
   });
  }
}

function lastElements() {
  var item = $(".last-elem").offset().top;
  var topWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (item < (topWindow + halfHeight)) { // CHANGES HERE
      $(".last-elem").each(function(i) {
          var el = $(this);
          setTimeout(function() {
              el.addClass("fadeinUp").removeClass("hidden");
          }, i * 500);
      });
  }
}
```